# Text-align doesn't work the same way on two identical div?

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

I've made a research before posting but I can't find anything to solve the problem.

I'm making a menu on my website, it has a width of 100% and inside the menu, I put 3 differents div.

**Managed to make them take 100% of the width**

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("images/triangles.svg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.1;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.left,
.center,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 30%;
}
.left {
  left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.right {
  right: 5%;
}
.center {
  width: 20%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <!--START-->
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#01">Element 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#02">Element 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#03">Element 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h3>Another Title</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#04">Element 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#05">Element 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#06">Element 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--END-->
```

My menu has an svg background but I don't think it's causing my issue. The problem is that inside .left and .right, the text-align doesn't works, but it does for the .center div. 
At the beginning my three div was in float left but as I tought it was the problem, I tried positionning is with absolute positions, but style not working.

I apply a background color to visualise the width of my div and the text is not center at all, obviously a "text-align: right" doesn't work too and I don't understand because .center and .left/.right are basically the same, I can't figure out what's the difference between .center and the other div.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the following styles

```
.menu li{float: left; list-style: none; margin-right: 5%;}
```

There is no space within which for you to see `text-align` have any effect on the text that you are referencing. This is because when you `float` those `li` they slim down to only the space required for their content.

That being so, it is most likely because of the `padding` and `margin` in your `ul` that you feel that `text-align` is the answer. See the following code

```
.right ul {margin: 0;padding:0;}
```

And the effect that it has:

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("images/triangles.svg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.1;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.left,
.center,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
}
.left {
  left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.right {
  right: 5%;
}
.center {
  width: 20%;
  left: 40%;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
.right ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <!--START-->
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#01">Element 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#02">Element 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#03">Element 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h3>Another Title</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#04">Element 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#05">Element 5</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#06">Element 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--END-->
```

Depending on what exact layout you are trying to achieve, there are a lot of options on how to wield the power that CSS gives you here, but hopefully this is enough of a first step to lead you towards where you were hoping to get.

Comment: Thanks ! It works fine ! I just transforme this float left in a "display inline" and that's all !